# Writing code for cuda and non-cuda compilers

Tags: c++, cuda, preprocessor

**Problem:**
We are writing Cuda code, which should also be compileable by non-cuda compilers (we use: nvcc, gcc and clang.)
Since Cuda needs those `__host__ __device__` annotations all around, we solved it by including the following header in each file in question:

**Our Solution:**

```cpp
// CudaTags.hpp
#ifndef CUDAFLAGS
    #define CUDAFLAGS
    #ifndef __CUDACC__
        #define __host__
        #define __device__
    #endif
#endif
```

So we can do in a source file:

```cpp
#include "CudaTags.hpp"
__host__ __device__ func();
```

**Questions:**
So far I do not see any (except, see *Note* below) problems with this approach. Thus,

- Do you see any problems I missed?
- What other possibilities are there out there to solve this problem?

---

*Note:* I know, my solution is UB, because I use identifiers starting with two underscores. Although also note, that it is *very* unlikely that this leads to UB, because the host compiler will never use this identifiers for themeself (since Cuda already took them).

Of course I could also do

```cpp
#ifndef CUDAFLAGS2
    #define CUDAFLAGS2
    #ifndef __CUDACC__
        #define CUDA_HOST
        #define CUDA_DEVICE
        #define CUDA_MANAGED
        #define CUDA_GLOBAL
    #else
        #define CUDA_HOST    __host__
        #define CUDA_DEVICE  __device__
        #define CUDA_MANAGED __managed__
        #define CUDA_GLOBAL  __global__
    #endif
#endif
```

and the use it as

```
CUDA_HOST CUDA_DEVICE void func();
```

But with this approach I have to use special names, clobber the global namespace and it looks very ugly.

Comment: It depends on the type of function you want to implement, but typically I can get away with marking those `constexpr` and [compile with `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constexpr-functions-and-function-templates). Shared functionality can then be compiled by CUDA and non-CUDA compilers, no macro magic required.

Comment: @Quxflux I am hesitant to use this, since 1) this feature is experimental for many years now and 2) with C++20s new constexpr rules, which allow memory allocation, I do not think this still works. Can you elaborate maybe a little bit more about it, how and when do you use it, which pitfalls are there and how to prevent uncaught logical errors?

Comment: An alternative solution is to define your own macro for the use in front of functions. See [how gsl-lite does it](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite/blob/a8c7e5bbbd08841836f9b92d72747fb8769dbec4/include/gsl/gsl-lite.hpp#L1152-L1158).